# Make css ( or something else ) format text so it won't go out of it's border

Tags: css, html

I have a page where it should show content. But when I have, for example: a long word, it goes out of the borders.

```
<table><tr><td id="contentholder" width="600px" valign="top">.........
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gekkeabt/qHPTs/
There you can see what I mean

What do I need to do so the very long word will be cut and put in a new line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

code:

```
#contentholder{
    max-width:600px;
    word-wrap:break-word;
}
```

and running: http://jsfiddle.net/NickWilde/qHPTs/3/

Answer (score 3):

Add the following into the #contentholder css:

```
word-wrap: break-word;
```

updated jsFiddle here - http://jsfiddle.net/qHPTs/2/

Comment: haha beat you by 2 seconds to the post - although obviously I was slower on saving the jsFiddle! but anyways I like your answer so +1

Comment: @Nick-BriarMoonDesign Now I don't know which one I have to choose as best answer...

Comment: generate a random number between 1 and 3?

Comment: I think I go for Nick's because he has less point. Sorry mara

Answer (score 3):

in your CSS

```
#contentholder{
    max-width:600px;
    word-wrap:break-word;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

add

```
word-wrap: break-word;
```

to

```
#contentholder
```

like this

```
#contentholder{
max-width:600px;
word-wrap: break-word;
}
```